# Moved module files, now getting failed opening required for previous file location

Tags: php, drupal, memcached

I am in the process of organizing my drupal site. All of my modules are located in /data/www-test/content/modules/. I created a folder called "contrib" and moved the contributed modules into there, so that all that was left is this directory was the core modules and 2 other directories (contrib and my custom modules, which I plan to move to sites/all/modules).

*I realize I should have put my site into maintenance mode and disabled the modules first.*

The first error I got was regarding the location of 'cache_inc', so I modified that (it is in my settings.php file) to be '/data/www-test/content/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc'.

Now, I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(dmemcache.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/www-test/content/modules/memcache/memcache.inc on line 4 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'dmemcache.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php5:/usr/local/lib/php') in /data/www-test/content/modules/memcache/memcache.inc on line 4
```

I'm confused however because memcache.inc is no longer located at /data/www-test/content/modules/memcache/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have drush installed run the command : drush registry-rebuild.
Else you can just truncate the cache tables : cache and cache_bootstrap (cache might not be needed, I just do it by habit). In sql : truncate cache; truncate cache_bootstrap;